# Which comments documentation format is better for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, documentation-generation, xml-documentation, vsdoc

Is there are any comments documentation format for JavaScript and processor for this format which generates HTML documentation?

Currently I am using VSDoc xml comments for providing IntelliSense help at developing time, but as I know there is no documentation generator for such comments.
So alternatively my question may sounds like: Is there are any utility which translates VSDoc comments from JavaScript files to HTML?

Comment: [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you looked at auto generated documentation from JavaDoc or VSDoc or JSDoc or anything like that.

They are all ugly and un-readable.

The solution is two fold

- [annotate your code with docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/)
- Make your API documentation hand written.

There is a third option which is to revolutionize the way we do auto generated documentation, if you can then please do.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) for a few projects. The syntax is nice for reading the inline, but since it doesn't have "full language support" for JavaScript, you have to be somewhat explicit about each function/constant/class/whatever you want to document.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility that parses Javascript files and outputs the same XML format NDoc and Sandcastle use: [AjaxDoc](http://ajaxdoc.codeplex.com/)

That way you get the VS intellisense from the same comments and can output any format that you want.